# How can I draw a line with a variable of width?

Tags: c++, variables, line

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "graph1.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int diameter = 0;
    int height = 0;
    double rate = 0;
    char repeat = 'y';
    int obj_num = 0;

    displayGraphics();

    obj_num = drawRect(0,0,50,400);
    setColor(obj_num,200,200,200);

    obj_num = drawRect(0,400,640,79);
    setColor(obj_num,71,35,35);

    obj_num = drawLine(50,50,150,50,5);
    setColor(obj_num,80,80,80);

    displayBMP("faucet.bmp",150,12);

    do
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter the diamater of the cylinder <in inches > 0 but <= 300: ";
            cin >> diameter;
        if((diameter<0) || (diameter>300))
        { 
            cout << "Incorrect diamater entered; value must be between 1 and 300" << endl;

        }
        }while((diameter<0) || (diameter>300));

        do
        {
            cout << "Enter the height of the cylinder <in inches > 0 but <= 325: ";
            cin >> height;
        if((height<0) || (height>325))
        {
            cout << "Incorrect height entered; value must be between 1 and 325" << endl;
        }

        }while((height<0) || (height>325));

        do
        {
            cout << "Enter the facet water's rate: <gallons/minute> ";
            cin >> rate;
        if((rate<0) || (rate>100))
        { 
            cout << "Incorrect rate entered; value must be between 1 and 100" << endl;

        }
        }while((rate<0) || (rate>100));


//I need to draw the lines here. The graphics window has a faucet that is supposed to fill 
//up a cylinder made out of 3 lines. I don't know how to make the lines vary from the users 
//input since lines are hard coded with points and all i am receiving is the width for the 
//bottom line and the height for the left and right lines. 

      cout << "Repeat program? (y/n): ";
      cin >> repeat;

      clearGraphics();

    }while ( (repeat == 'y') || (repeat == 'Y') );
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a screenshot for reference:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

How to draw a thicker line largely depends on what your graphics library provides. In the case of this specific question, it looks like you're using a library provided by your instructor, so specific help on that will be sparse on Stack Overflow. Ask your instructor, or check the documentation provided with your course materials.

Based on the position of the faucet pipe in your assignment and the command used to draw it, it looks like the **final parameter of `drawLine`** is the width:

```
obj_num = drawLine(50,50,150,50,5);
```

If you have no library-provided way of drawing thicker lines, you can always use the brute-force way and simply **draw multiple adjacent lines**. For your assignment, you're supposed to draw the cylinder walls four pixels thick, so draw four lines, each one with an *x* coordinate one more than the previous.

Another way to draw thick lines is to instead **draw rectangles** that are the thickness you want. Define a rectangle that is four pixels wide, and then draw it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have variable **height**
when you call drawline function, plug in this variable.